# Hidden Members on FB groups

Tags: facebook-groups

A member I want to delete from a Facebook Group is not showing up on the members list. And he keeps taunting and abusing the group asking us Admins to remove him, which we can't because he is not showing up on the member list. And it seems like he is adding more vicious members to the group now and they are abusing members. The admins have reported to FB and when we block them we are not able to see their posts but the remaining group members can, and it's even tougher then! What is happening?

Comment: None of the current answers work. I can in fact see the member who has blocked me's posts and I can delete these posts but I can't see him in the member list.

Comment: According to facebook (currently) this* can't happen. They say "A group member can block the group admin, but that member's group activity will still be visible to the admin." at https://www.facebook.com/help/1818045045155371 (click for ore context).  *On the other hand*, I've seen posts that say they have n comments, but I can see fewer than n comments under the post. (E.g. 3 vs 2 posts - happened yesterday in a group I admin.  I don't know what explains this.)

Answer (score 4):

You should report the situation to Facebook as soon as possible.

See [this page](http://www.facebook.com/safety/tools/), which recommends

> Report Abusive or Offensive Content
>
> Tell us about any content that violates the Facebook Terms. The most efficient way to report abuse is to do it right where it occurs on Facebook, using the “Report” link near the post, profile or Page.

In most cases, click on the `X` next to any post to access the menu with this feature.

Answer (score 2):

Quietly create a new group and invite members one by one.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that the trolls in your group have blocked the admins from seeing them, or their posts, and you can't ban someone from the group unless you can see them.

You have to be quick when you do the following, because, if the the trolls are smart, they will quickly block any new admin, but if you are quick, you can delete all trolls, and seal up the group.

First find a friendly (non-troll) member of the group, who is not an admin of the group, and who is able to see all of the trolls posts. Explain to that member that you need their help in eradicating the trolls. Then explain to that member how to kick someone out of the group. It can be done from the group members list, or from any comment by any troll.

Then make sure that the friendly member is ready to carry out the bannings AS SOON AS you make them an admin of the group.

Then make them an admin of the group, and encourage them to delete all troll members as quickly as possible. And when they do they must choose the option to permanently ban the trolls.

Also change your group settings so that new members can only be added to the group by group admins.

That should get rid of your trolls, and keep them locked out.

Comment: What if they don't post anything , but just comment to the posts ?

Answer (score 1):

If you have a member of your group that has blocked Admins, their name will turn BLACK. It will keep you from commenting on any post they have, but you can see them and any comments on the post.

What you do is take note of that member's name, then go to your members list and search for that person.

When they come up, go to that little tool and it will allow you to remove the person from your group (you even have the option to ban them, to be sure they never "accidentally" become a member again).

I just did this to three members who I didn't know had banned the Admins, as well as the person on my group wall who blocked Admins just recently.  So I recommend every once in a while, scroll your members list and remove any names in black.

Comment: No, such member is not longer visible in member list.

Answer (score 0):

Just go to group search, enter his name, find his post, comment on it or tell any other member to comment, now go back to group. His post will be in the top. Click on the post's options drawer and click delete and ban.. job done

Answer (score 0):

Download the Facebook App on your phone, and then search through your members' list on it.
I couldn't see one member on my computer, but I could on my phone by using the app.

Comment: This doesn't provide answer.